# Sequelize Date returning wrong date (minus 1)

Tags: javascript, express, sequelize.js

One of my tables has a field called birthdate with a Data Type of Date but when I try to export the data via an Express app it changes the date to one less than it should be.  For example a birthdate really is 6/20/1978 when I export it becomes 6/19/1978.

Something I noticed I noticed while logging out the data was even though it's a Date only field something (Sequelize?) is adding the time stamps to it.  So if I don't do any formatting (which I need to) to the date then the date will be correct but not readable for our exports.

When I run the app from my development notebook everything works great but when I push to QA it returns the wrong dates.

If I open PG3Admin from my notebook (which is located in the Pacific timezone) to query the data on the QA/Production server (which is located in Hawaiian timezone) the data looks correct.

I am using Sequelize v3.4.1 connecting to a Postgres 9.3 database.  Also in my Sequelize config file I have set the "timezone": "-10:00" option.

Comment: It is recommended you use UTC to store the dates in the database and only set the timezone for display

Comment: The Sequelize community seemed to recommend otherwise.  The odd part is in the database it's only storing the date with no time.

Comment: Could you please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70267786/6011421)

Answer (score 0):

it's better to store with datatype DATEONLY in sequelize, and use DATE for timestamp

according to [github source](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/src/data-types.js#L455)

```
_applyTimezone(date, options) {
  if (options.timezone) {
    if (momentTz.tz.zone(options.timezone)) {
      return momentTz(date).tz(options.timezone);
    }
    return (date = moment(date).utcOffset(options.timezone)); <-- this will convert your date to UTC
  }
  return momentTz(date);
}
```

you need to define your timezone in sequelize configuration, in case birthday is better use DATEONLY datatype

so your model can be like

```
birthday: {
  type: DataTypes.DATEONLY
},
createdAt: {
  type: DataTypes.DATE
},
updatedAt: {
  type: DataTypes.DATE
}
```

all datatype can see in [doc](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-basics.html)

Comment: Please add an example here instead of linking to an external document. While the external document might include the answer now, it can change at any time, making your answer worthless

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this is the best solution, but it worked for me:

```
Sequelize.YOURDIALECT.DATEONLY.parse = function(value) {
    return moment(moment(value).format('YYYY-MM-DD'), "YYYY-MM-DD").add(1, 'days');
};
```

Hope this will be helpful to others.